# Which gem is supposed to use to work with firefox using watir

Tags: watir

I Tried with Installing gem Watir-WebDriver but it is not working. It's saying:

```
C:\Ruby187>gem install watir web-driver
Successfully installed watir-2.0.4
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'web-driver' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: megadriver, view_driver, testdrive, app_driver, web-facter
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for watir-2.0.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for watir-2.0.4...
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you mean [`watir-webdriver`](https://rubygems.org/gems/watir-webdriver)? If that doesn't work, can you post the output of `gem source`?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page on how to install watir-webdriver gem: https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/blob/master/installation/windows.md

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the system to install two gems, one named 'watir', the other named 'web-driver'.

The watir gem exists, and is being installed.  However, it is only for driving IE  (firefox used to be supported via firewatir, but changes post 3.6 made it impossible to continue to support 'firewatir')

**There is no gem named 'web-driver'  which is what the error is telling you.**

What you want to install is **watir-webdriver**.  This is a version of watir that uses webdriver to drive the browsers, and offers cross browser support including latest versions of IE, Firefox, and Chrome..

See the [link](https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/blob/master/installation/windows.md) @Zeljko provided for detailed installation instructions for watir-webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

use `gem install watir-webdriver`.